# Import private key ripple

Tags: json-rpc, ripple, ripple-api

Is there a way to import private key with rippled?

Same as bitcoin core impoertprivkey with RPC calls?

Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the rippled API documentation it would seem that there is no import private key call - https://developers.ripple.com/rippled-api.html

However other ripple clients can do this task.  I know of the https://toastwallet.com/ as a stand alone Ripple wallet but it seems some people have had issues importing private keys.

https://gatehub.net/ is another alternative for a desktop ripple client and in here you can import the private keys and import addresses into your wallet.

Your private key is your account. You can access your account from any wallet that is a portal to the xrp ledger.

Gatehub will easily let you restore your private key. People have issuings restoring with toast cause the toast backup requirement.